# Object with fixed Y-axis that follows the mouse on X-axis

Tags: javascript, css

I need help for an effect I'm trying to create: I made a CSS triangle and I want it to be fixed on the Y-axis but follow the mouse on his X-axis (didn't you read the title ?!). If it's not clear, I want it to move only to the left/right but not up/down. I managed to apply a js script I found on the internet to my triangle but I can't figure out how to change it to stop it from moving on the Y-axis. When I try to change anything, the whole thing doesn't move anymore. Can some one help me ?

```js
// Here get the Div that you want to follow the mouse
var div_moving = document.getElementById('div_moving');

// Here add the ID of the parent element
var parent_div = 'parent_div';

// object to make a HTML element to follow mouse cursor ( http://coursesweb.net/ )
var movingDiv = {
  mouseXY: {},  // will contain the X, Y mouse coords inside its parent

  // Get X and Y position of the elm (from: vishalsays.wordpress.com/ )
  getXYpos: function(elm) {
    x = elm.offsetLeft;        // set x to elm’s offsetLeft
    y = elm.offsetTop;         // set y to elm’s offsetTop

    elm = elm.offsetParent;    // set elm to its offsetParent

    //use while loop to check if elm is null
    // if not then add current elm’s offsetLeft to x, offsetTop to y and set elm to its offsetParent
    while(elm != null) {
      x = parseInt(x) + parseInt(elm.offsetLeft);
      y = parseInt(y) + parseInt(elm.offsetTop);
      elm = elm.offsetParent;
    }

    // returns an object with "xp" (Left), "=yp" (Top) position
    return {'xp':x, 'yp':y};
  },

  // Returns object with X, Y coords inside its parent
  getCoords: function(e) {
    var xy_pos = this.getXYpos(e.target);

    // if IE
    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
      var standardBody = (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat') ? document.documentElement : document.body;

      x = event.clientX + standardBody.scrollLeft;
      y = event.clientY + standardBody.scrollTop;
    }
    else {
      x = e.pageX;
      y = e.pageY;
    }

    x = x - xy_pos['xp'];
    y = y - xy_pos['yp'];

    return {'xp':x, 'yp':y};
  }
};


// registers 'mousemove' event to parent_div
document.getElementById(parent_div).addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
  mouseXY = movingDiv.getCoords(e);
  div_moving.style.left = mouseXY.xp + 8 +'px';
  div_moving.style.top = mouseXY.yp - 8 +'px';
});
```

```css
#parent_div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border; 1px solid #333;
  background: #fefebe;
}
#div_moving {
  position: absolute;
  width: 41em;
  height: 31em;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #33f;
  background: #88ee99;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container {
    width: 37.5em;
    height: 37.5em;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 20px solid #e74c3c;
    left:3%;
}

.triangle {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    top: -20em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width:31em;
    height:31em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-right: 20px solid #e74c3c;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent_div">
  <div id="div_moving">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="triangle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  Content in parent ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just reformatted a little, then commented one line and it's working in Chrome on my machine.  Is this what you're looking for?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            // object to make a HTML element to follow mouse cursor ( http://coursesweb.net/ )
            var movingDiv = {
              mouseXY: {},  // will contain the X, Y mouse coords inside its parent

              // Get X and Y position of the elm (from: vishalsays.wordpress.com/ )
              getXYpos: function(elm) {
                x = elm.offsetLeft;        // set x to elm’s offsetLeft
                y = elm.offsetTop;         // set y to elm’s offsetTop

                elm = elm.offsetParent;    // set elm to its offsetParent

                //use while loop to check if elm is null
                // if not then add current elm’s offsetLeft to x, offsetTop to y and set elm to its offsetParent
                while(elm != null) {
                  x = parseInt(x) + parseInt(elm.offsetLeft);
                  y = parseInt(y) + parseInt(elm.offsetTop);
                  elm = elm.offsetParent;
                }

                // returns an object with "xp" (Left), "=yp" (Top) position
                return {'xp':x, 'yp':y};
              },

              // Returns object with X, Y coords inside its parent
              getCoords: function(e) {
                var xy_pos = this.getXYpos(e.target);

                // if IE
                if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) {
                  var standardBody = (document.compatMode == 'CSS1Compat') ? document.documentElement : document.body;

                  x = event.clientX + standardBody.scrollLeft;
                  y = event.clientY + standardBody.scrollTop;
                }
                else {
                  x = e.pageX;
                  y = e.pageY;
                }

                x = x - xy_pos['xp'];
                y = y - xy_pos['yp'];

                return {'xp':x, 'yp':y};
              }
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Here get the Div that you want to follow the mouse
                var div_moving = document.getElementById('div_moving');

                // Here add the ID of the parent element
                var parent_div = 'parent_div';
                // registers 'mousemove' event to parent_div
                document.getElementById(parent_div).addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
                  mouseXY = movingDiv.getCoords(e);
                  div_moving.style.left = mouseXY.xp + 8 +'px';
                  //div_moving.style.top = mouseXY.yp - 8 +'px';
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            #parent_div {
              position: relative;
              width: 100%;
              height: 800px;
              margin: 1em auto;
              border; 1px solid #333;
              background: #fefebe;
            }
            #div_moving {
              position: absolute;
              width: 41em;
              height: 31em;
              margin: 0;
              border: 1px solid #33f;
              background: #88ee99;
              overflow:hidden;
            }
            .container {
                width: 37.5em;
                height: 37.5em;
                position: relative;
                border-top: 20px solid #e74c3c;
                left:3%;
            }

            .triangle {
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
                top: -20em;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                width:31em;
                height:31em;
                transform: rotate(45deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
                border-right: 20px solid #e74c3c;
                border-bottom: 20px solid #e74c3c;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="parent_div">
          <div id="div_moving">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="triangle"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          Content in parent ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Differences:

- Load the JQuery script first
- Process the listener in a ready function so all the content has been loaded
- Comment out the Y positioning

Comment: Can't find your comment but I updated the fiddle with your script and it doesn't work :/ https://jsfiddle.net/eL96o34q/1/ EDIT : added the script inside the HTML and it works, I guess the problem was jquery not being loaded

Comment: I un checked the "good answer" because there's a little problem: the div now gets out of its parent div :/ + moving from right to left has no problem but left to right is a bit buggy !

Comment: Addin overflow:hidden to the parent div fixes the problem and I like it better that way (other than going back if you get out from the right) but moving from right to left is still staggering. Edit : it actually works great unless your mouse is on the same level as the moving div

Comment: It actually goes crazy when the mouse is ON the div cause it doesn't know where to go. Maybe find a way to tell the div not to move if it doesn't know where to go

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found a solution to my problem.
So here the problems and what I did:

- I wanted the object to move only on X-axis and not Y: IgnusFast found out the line to delete was "div_moving.style.top = mouseXY.yp - 8 +'px';"
- I wanted it to stop staggering when the mouse passed over it: deleted "parseInt(x) +" in "while(elm != null) {x = parseInt(x) + parseInt(elm.offsetLeft); elm = elm.offsetParent;}" (makes the div stay where it is when not sure.
- I wanted it to center with the mouse instead of being on its right: original was " div_moving.style.left = mouseXY.xp + 8 +'px';" wich made it go 8 pixels to the right of the current mouse's coordinates so I just used a negative number and place like this :" div_moving.style.left = mouseXY.xp + -350 +'px';"